# How to insert image tag in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 {
   ques: "Panitia sembilan diketuai oleh",
   ans: ". Ir. Soekarno",
   ansSel: ["Moh. Hatta", "Moh. Yamin","Ahmad Soebardjo","Mr. Soepomo"]
 }
```

How to insert image tag (in ques? I use [jQuizMe](http://code.google.com/p/jquizme) in my project.

I try:

`ques:"<img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">"` but it isnt working...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? An actual image element? This method works if you want to convert that string into it using a wrapper `wrapper.innerHTML= '<img src="..."/>'`, but if you want an actual image node you should make it with `let image = new Image(); image.src = src; item.image = image;`

Comment: Are you able to store the src and alt in an object inside the array and then construct the image from this?

Comment: question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `\` to escape the `"` or you can use single quote `'`

#### Method1:

```
ques:"<img src=\"pic_trulli.jpg\" alt=\"Italian Trulli\">"
```

#### Method2:

```
ques:"<img src='pic_trulli.jpg' alt='Italian Trulli'>"
```